# C++ lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Tags: c++

I'm working on a game engine and working on implementing a state design. I have an Engine class which takes care of all the initialization of everything and contains the game loop which calls update, render and handle input functions of the active state.

All my different states inherit from State which requires a reference to the Engine class in its constructor, in order to initialize the protected reference of the engine for future use. Here's the relevant code:

```
// file: state.h
class Engine;

class State {
public:

    State(Engine &engine) : mEngine(engine) { }
protected:
    Engine &mEngine;
};

// file: gamestate.h
class GameState : public State {
public:
    GameState(Engine &engine) : State(engine) {}
};
```

and finally in engine.cpp in the initializer I create a new GameState object, which is where the error is reported.

```
GameState *state = new GameState(&this);
```

I'm coding it in C++ using Qt Creator on Linux at the minute, don't have access to a windows machine right now to see if it's a problem with the gcc or not.

Comment: Why not have extern'd global pointers rather than member pointers?

Comment: @Shaktal No, it wouldn't be possible to chose an engine. Injection is a good thing. and global variable certainly a bad thing. In fact `state` should not even be a member of the engine. Moreover C++ is a modern language., stop messing with pointers where you don't have to!! Why not simply `Engine engine; GameState state(engine)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
 GameState *state = new GameState(&this);
```

to:

```
GameState *state = new GameState(*this);
```

This is because you are passing the Engine by reference to the constructor of the State class.

Comment: @Jesus but `this` is a pointer not a reference - he needs to dereference it in order to pass it as a reference.

Comment: Oh you're right it's been a while since I did some C++ and I got it confused with C#/Java style

Comment: Cheers! That solved it :) About reference instead of pointer - don't have a good reason really so Ill just blame the heatwave for doing it this way. Still fairly new to C++ so is there any noticeable differnece?

Comment: @grouse: I recommend that you keep doing it. Passing references (rather than pointers) makes it clear that the receiving end is not responsible for the management of the object that is passed, and it makes it explicit that it cannot be null either. Prefer references to pointers whenever possible. Then prefer smart pointers to pointers, and only resort to raw pointers when there is no alternative (or a strong reason to do so)

Comment: @David - Thanks, that makes sense, I will remove that from my solution and hopefully people will take note of your comment :)